# How to use MINUS in google bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to do MINUS on 2 tables which have same schema in big-query.As I understand MINUS is not working in biquery

Comment: By "minus" you mean removing the intersection between the tables?

Comment: perhaps use the "in" SQL syntax? 
`select * form table1 where val in (select val from table2)`

Comment: By Minus I mean the records which are in Table A and not in Table B.Minus will remove the common records also.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT 
   field
FROM `project_id.dataset.tableA` A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `project_id.dataset.tableB` b WHERE a.field = b.field)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that there is EXCEPT set operator in Big Query for Standard SQL.
The EXCEPT operator returns rows from the left input query that are not present in the right input query. This is similar to what the MINUS does in ORACLE/MySQL
SELECT fieldId from `dataset.table1` except DISTINCT SELECT fieldId from `dataset.table2`

Note: the datatype of both the columns should be same in both the tables